# The command line is weird after creating a new screen

Tags: command-line, 18.04, restart

Well when I log in, I normally see `username@name:directory#` but when I go to my screen, created by an bash script every restart `screen -S "Name" -d -m`, it only displays a `#`. Additionally commands like `reboot` or executing files don't work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Care to share your `/etc/screenrc` and/or `~/.screenrc`?

Comment: Thanks alot! /etc/screenrc does not exist for me.

Comment: Does everything work normally if you change your command to `screen -l -S "Name" -d -m` ?

Comment: What will `-l` do, start the screen as a user?

Comment: `username@name:directory#` and `#` are displayed through the `PS1` environment variable, see `man $SHELL` about `PROMPTING`

Comment: `-l` forces screen to create a _login_ shell. Probably your `PS1` gets loaded only when the shell is a login one.

Comment: Well not really, would it help if I use `su`?

Comment: Well I fixed it by using `screen -r "Name" -X stuff $'su\n'`. How can I close this question/mark it as solved?